# Why Marmalade has so strange naming?

Tags: syntax, marmalade

I've read some tutorial about Marmalade Framework. You know... it's totally awesome :)
For example:

```
// Creating an Image from a Web Based Image File:
CIwGameFile* image_file = new CIwGameFile();
image_file->Open( "http://site...../icon.gif", false, true );
image_file->Close();

// Now we will create a sprite to display our downloaded web image:
CIwGameBitmapSprite* test_sprite = new CIwGameBitmapSprite();
test_sprite->setImage( image );
test_sprite->setDestSize( image->getWidth(), image->getHeight() );
```

WHY?? Why the first methods have uppercase (Open, Close) name and the second ones in lowercase (setImage, getWidth)? Is there any common sense when they do that? Or Marmalade has SO aweful syntax in whole library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marmalade uses `Upper Camel case` for all of it's methods (as far as I've seen). The methods you are talking about is not Marmalade's own API methods. These are `IwGame` engine's methods. Marmalade has no control on this.

Answer (score 2):

IwGame uses first letter lower case for setters and getters

Comment: I just don't like upper camel case :))) I wish Marmalade has lower camel case haha :)) It's so hard to work with the lower camel case and the upper camel case in one project (if I use lwGame with Marmalade).